# ASP MVC - Getting Controller Level error handling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

How to get Controller-Level error handling:

This is my map-route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",                                              // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

And I have 2 controllers - HomeController and AwayController

I want both both controllers to handle their own errors

For example, a call to

/Home/InvalidAction would be handled by one method

and

/Away/InvalidAction would be handled by another method

Where InvalidAction currently results in a 404 as there's no Action method with that name

Answer (score 1):

You can override `OnUnknownAction` method in your controller to catch when a request is made to the controller with no matching action method.  You can also override `OnException` to catch unhandled exceptions thrown in your controller's action methods.

Andrew